# Dynamically Added btns with different PopOvers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, popup

*For an express/node/mongo app, elements are being dynamically added from the db.*

**Only the first button returns a popOver though, when excluding the for-loop..**

JAVASCRIPT

```
function createPopOver(selector, content) {
    $('body').popover({
        selector: selector,
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'right',
        content: content,
        html: true
    });
}    

function addBtn()
{
    for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++) {

        $('.buttons').append("<p><a class='btn' rel='popOver" + i + "'>popOver</a></p>");

        createPopOver('[rel="popOver' + i + '"]', 'content for ' + i);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div class="container">

    <button type="button" class="btn" onClick="addBtn()">addBtn</button>

    <div class="buttons">   </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Why on earth are you generating javascript like that?

Comment: @JasonP to avoid document.write.. Way open to any suggestions

Comment: I would do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/EdBc8/

Comment: Far better. Appreciate the best-practice. Am only getting one button to appear though (without the for-loop).. Will a loop work for this?

Comment: That looks better. Now `.html()` will _replace_ the existing content with the specified content. Try `.append()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, good to know.. Am only getting it to generate 1 button, without the for loop though. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oops, I'm mixing my c# and javascript. It's `for (var i = 0; ...`

Comment: Nice! Like magic.. The buttons appeared, but no popovers yet - maybe a bootstrap thing? Thanks for all of this btw

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't have any experience with the popover plugin. Maybe if you made a jsfiddle.

Comment: Because I moved your loop & createPopOver call to the addBtn call, with the button .append(), it seems as though the popOvers might only exist during the onClick event.. Where would createPopOver best be called instead?

Comment: Put this together, but for whatever reason jsfiddle won't call the function (when testing it there, it said something about making it a post call).. Anyway, here's http://jsfiddle.net/zYF8R/1/ with bootstrap external resources

Comment: Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/yTXZ8/. It looks like maybe an element can only have one popover bound to it? So I'm binding the popover directly to the new elements instead of the body.